# How to merge 2 pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 pandas Series (`s1`, and `s2`) like this:

```
import pandas as pd

index1 = list(range(6))
index2 = list(range(2, 8))

data1 = [7, 6, 1, 9, 3, 4]
data2 =       [1, 9, 3, 4, 10, 12]

s1 = pd.Series(data=data1, index=index1)
s2 = pd.Series(data=data2, index=index2)
```

`s1` and `s2` have some common indices. And they have the same value at the corresponding  index.

How can I use `s1` and `s2` to create a new Series `s3` that contains the following content:

```
>>> print(s3)
0     7
1     6
2     1
3     9
4     3
5     4
6    10
7    12
```

Here's another example of the merge:

```
import pandas as pd

index1 = list(range(6))
index2 = list(range(8, 14))

data1 = [7, 6, 1, 9, 3, 4]
data2 = [7, 2, 5, 6, 10, 12]

s1 = pd.Series(data=data1, index=index1)
s2 = pd.Series(data=data2, index=index2)

s3 = merge(s1, s2)

print(s3)

# 0      7
# 1      6
# 2      1
# 3      9
# 4      3
# 5      4
# 8      7
# 9      2
# 10     5
# 11     6
# 12    10
# 13    12
# dtype: int64
```

In this example, `s1` and `s2` don't have common indices.

Comment: What is the exact logic? Is there always a single part of overlap? Is order important? Can it overlap in the middle? It's difficult to provide an exact answer without details (I can give you at least 3 different solutions that give this output but won't generalize the same way)

Comment: `s1` and `s2` might have 0 or 1 overlap part. Order is important.

Comment: Wait a moment. Let me provide more examples in my question.

Comment: Also, can there be duplicates in each Series?

Comment: Wait, I hadn't seen that the index are already aligned, then it's straightforward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your indices are already aligned, then you can use a simple [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
out = s1.combine_first(s2).convert_dtypes()
```

output:

```
0     7
1     6
2     1
3     9
4     3
5     4
6    10
7    12
dtype: Int64
```

second example output:

```
0      7
1      6
2      1
3      9
4      3
5      4
8      7
9      2
10     5
11     6
12    10
13    12
dtype: Int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s3=pd.Index(s1).union(pd.Index(s2)).to_series()
s3
```

out

```
0     7
1     6
2     1
3     9
4     3
5     4
6    10
7    12
```